# Is "str" a legit sound in Polish?

Tags: phonology, polish

"str" is legit in generic Slavic ("*strel-", arrow), so I wonder if Polish has it, maybe in leanwords. A small dictionary computer search  gave nothing. (Frankly, I just want to see a "szczrz" in print...OK, I'm German, we still can easily top that :-)

Comment: Polish has *strzela*. I have searched a Polish corpus for "szczrz" with zero hits as a result.

Comment: leanwords? Like skinny? Or loanwords like borrowings? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a text corpus - even the small guest [Araneum Polonicum Minus](http://aranea.juls.savba.sk/guest/run.cgi/corp_info?corpname=AranPolo_x) gives you already [a lot of concordances](http://aranea.juls.savba.sk/guest/run.cgi/first?corpname=AranPolo_x&reload=&iquery=&queryselector=wordrow&word=str.*) with word-initial *str-* (and that's just the word-initial).

You can check the
[frequency distribution](http://aranea.juls.savba.sk/guest/run.cgi/freqml?q=q%5Blc%3D%22str.*%22%5D&corpname=AranPolo_x&refs=%3Ddoc.urldomain&ml=1&flimit=0&freqlevel=1&ml1attr=word&ml1ctx=0%7E0%3E0&ml2attr=word&ml2ctx=0%7E0%3E0&ml3attr=word&ml3ctx=0%7E0%3E0&ml4attr=word&ml4ctx=0%7E0%3E0&ml5attr=word&ml5ctx=0%7E0%3E0) and see the most frequent word is *strona*, followed by *strata* and derivatives of *strach*. All perfectly legit.

Although, -r- in Polish is not syllabic, unlike in e.g. Czech or Slovak, which (phonotactically) somewhat diminishes the possibilities. Compare the pronunciation (stress) of Polish *trwa* (one syllable) with Slovak *trvá* (two syllables).

Comment: So "st"->"szcz" (e.g. Szczecin) but "str"->"str"? You live, you learn. (No wonder I didn't find "str" - I didn't search...)

Comment: I think _r_ tends to become _rz_ only in front (or palatalized) contexts.